# What is the pattern or relation in this table?

Tags: pattern-recognition

Here is the table:

$$\begin{array}{c}
0\\  
1\\  
1& 1\\  
3& 2& 3\\  
5& 3& 3& 5\\  
11 &8 &10 &8 &11\\  
21 &13 &14 &14 &13 &21\\  
43 &30 &37 &36 &37 &30 &43\\  
85 &55 &61 &55 &55 &61 &55 &85\\  
171 &116 &140 &140 &146 &140 &140 &116 &171  
\end{array}$$

In this triangle like table, I am unable to find the relation between columnwise.
Say for 1st column, I have found the relation $A(n)= A(n-1)+2A(n-2)$.

For the 2nd column, I have the relation $A(n)= A(n-1)+2A(n-2) + x$ [ where $x$ is $-1$ for even row number and $+1$ for odd].

But for other columns, I have not found the relations yet. Can anyone help me find a generalized equation to generate the table?

Comment: Where did you get this table?

Comment: in the second last row, shouldn't there be a 85 instead of the 65? :)

Comment: @Alex , yes, fixed.

Comment: there are definitively some interesting patterns in this table! just can't get my head around it at the moment

Comment: Just out of interest, what is this table for?

Comment: The first column and the diagonal appear to be [A001045](http://oeis.org/A001045), $J_n = \frac{2^n-(-1)^n}{3}$. [Wikipedia has an article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_number), too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated:**
let $A(n,k)$ be the number in the table with row $n$ and column $k$, where $0\le n$ and $0\le k\le n$.

$$A(n,k)=A(n,n-k)$$
$$A(n,0)=A(n,n)=0$$

The table would look like this: (top left is row $0$ and column $0$)

$$\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0& 0\\  
0& 1& 0\\  
0& 1& 1& 0\\  
0& 3& 2& 3& 0\\  
0& 5& 3& 3& 5& 0\\  
0& 11 &8 &10 &8 &11& 0\\  
0& 21 &13 &14 &14 &13 &21& 0\\  
0& 43 &30 &37 &36 &37 &30 &43& 0\\  
0& 85 &55 &61 &55 &55 &61 &55 &85& 0\\  
0& 171 &116 &140 &140 &146 &140 &140 &116 &171  & 0
\end{array}$$

Then, we have: $$A(n+1,k)+A(n,k)+A(n,k-1)=2^{n-1}$$

---

**Example**
$$A(8,3)+A(7,3)+A(7,2)=37+14+13=64=2^6$$

Comment: how 4C2 gives 8 ? i am unable to understand your example.

Comment: @HamadZaraf yeah sorry, that was the wrong row. it should have been 5.

Comment: The choice of binomial coefficient is strange and a bit confusing.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Is it better now?